# Undefined reference to IEE_EmoEnginEventCreat()

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm working on a Raspberry Pi3 project with C++ code running rasbian stretch OS. I cloned the code from https://github.com/Emotiv/community-sdk. First I installed `CMake` but when I type `$make` in the terminal, the following  **[Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5xM7.png)** appear. I tried to put all the header files inside the project folder but the error still there. Any suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: Put the errors as text instead of an image.

Comment: According to the project's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/Emotiv/community-sdk/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt), you should run `cmake` from the top-level source directory. Running `cmake` from the example's directory won't work.